# How can i search where it is used liferay default language property?

Tags: properties, liferay, liferay-6

I want to change `Liferay` default language property, but i dont know in what places it uses.

I find a full list of `liferay` properties here [Language_eu.properties](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/master/portal-impl/src/content/Language_eu.properties)

I used a hook to change a default value, imagine i want to change this key:

```
to= [toInEuLanguage]
```

But i dont know full context of all cases `liferay` it uses this key.

Imagine i put that on the key:

```
to= -
```

And liferay use it on this case:

> Correct:
>
> - 15 to 20 results
> - `EU:` 15 - 20 results_eu

But maybe liferay it uses on other case like this (not real case):

> Incorrect:
>
> - Time to leave
> - `EU:` Time_eu - leave_eu

---

Exactly want to change a literal used on liferay default pagination.
I used liferay pagination on a template, and by default administration of liferay uses it too.

Is there a way to check where liferay use a particular key and the context of it?

Comment: Hard to find out all places where a small word like this is involved.
It's better to hook JSPs you want to change the particular case

Comment: @DanieleBaggio i want to change the literal of liferay default pagination `of` key. Is possible to do that without hook all `JSPs` involved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid it is next to impossible to find all the places a key is used. Anything (portlet, servlet, service, jsp page, template, theme, ...) can request any key at any time. There is nothing that keeps track of what uses what key.

I'm not sure why you want to change the default but that is usually not a good idea. If something is wrongly translated or should be changed globally, the best way is to use https://crowdin.com/project/liferay-portal and get in touch with proofreaders for the given language.

If you want to customize existing application, then you should look how that is used in that particular application. It may be the same challenge but the scope is much much narrower.

If you only want to make use of the key in your application then the best option is to have own properties.

Comment: i have my own properties, but want to translate couple of "default" liferay props. We have a template that uses liferay default pagination and that mean liferay default literals, and we want to change it on all liferays paginations (that includes liferay administration too). But as you said, its better to request for a translate of it?